# How to disable fields in a fieldset?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

I am using this code to disable fields in the form based from what I have searched in stackoverflow:

```
jQuery('#reportFilters').children(':input').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

But it does not work.

Does joomla have something to do with this?

I tried this on a single field and this worked:

```
    jQuery('#jform_id_5').prop("disabled","disabled");
```

It worked for a single field. However, the reason I want to use the fieldset is because fields under the fieldset are dynamically generated. They are not pre-defined in the view. For example I have  different reports with different filters, each filter is a different input field.

Comment: I think you have a typo here: if you write `input` instead of `:input` you could find all input tags below of `#reportFilters`.

Comment: Open up the console in developer tools and run the above statement. May be there are some errors. If not then try to run jQuery('#reportFilters').children(':input'); . This will return you like array of your desired elements.